# How to make a flex container display the divs in row when screen size decreases (width)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I want to make this flex container (.flex-container) able to display the divs in rows whenever the screen size decreases. This flex container has a gird container inside as well. I want the blue div to go first and the red container to go below it. I have tried flex-direction and changing the display of the grid container to flex but It has not worked.

Here's my code:

```css
.flex-container {
  height: 900px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
}

.my-info-menu {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 800px;
  width: 25%;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
}

.grid-container {
  width: 95%;
  height: 600px;
  display: grid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}

.grid-item {
  background: red;
  color: blueviolet;
  height: 80%;
  width: 95%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
  .flex-container {
    height: 2000px;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .grid-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">



<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="my-info-menu"></div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-item">1</div>
      <div class="grid-item">2</div>
      <div class="grid-item">3</div>
      <div class="grid-item">4</div>
      <div class="grid-item">5</div>
      <div class="grid-item">6</div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With `flex`, you can use `flex-wrap` and `min-width` to create breakpoints . `flex` or `grid` can easily use the `gap` property and `flex-grow` (or `fr` ) rules to dispatch and create ruler in between elements.

here is an example of what i guess you try to do.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1em;
}

.my-info-menu {
  background-color: blue;
  min-width: 25%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.container {
  min-width: 500px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  gap: 1em;
}

.grid-item {
  background: red;
  color: blueviolet
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="my-info-menu">run me in full page mode<br> reset the min-width value to set where break points should happend<br> same for the min-height value of container , if screenHeight is not what you need.</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-item">1</div>
      <div class="grid-item">2</div>
      <div class="grid-item">3</div>
      <div class="grid-item">4</div>
      <div class="grid-item">5</div>
      <div class="grid-item">6</div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, thank you for correcting on me the format!